# Send Secondary MX Records

Tags: mx-record

I am quite new on administrating so any pointing to the right direction is appreciated.
My mails are send through gmail, which communicates with my mail server that is hosted on centos 6.8, plesk 12.5 and postfix 2.11.5.

My mails to a specific domain are rejected. I can see in my logs that the mail server to which my mails are going is different than the domain of the recipient of the mail.

Contacting the support team of the recipient, the told me that I send the mails to their secondary MX Record and not to their Primary MX Record.

I though this is managed by the recipient mail server.The mail is send to an address and the the recipient MTA figures out how this mail is going to be manipulated.

Is it possible to determine to which MX Record I send the mail?

Bellow is an excerpt from my mail logs

```
Oct 17 13:36:24 ct603 postfix/smtp[5763]: 433342606DE: to=<uwfd@groupama-phoenix.com>, relay=none, delay=248135, delays=248134/0.01/0.83/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to dr.groupama-phoenix.com[195.170.5.242]:25: Connection refused)
Oct 17 13:56:24 ct603 postfix/smtp[6289]: connect to dr.groupama-phoenix.com[195.170.5.242]:25: Connection refused
Oct 17 13:56:24 ct603 postfix/smtp[6289]: 3D65C26252A: to=<bakogianniss@groupama.gr>, relay=none, delay=13023, delays=13023/0.03/0.38/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to dr.groupama-phoenix.com[195.170.5.242]:25: Connection refused)
Oct 17 14:46:24 ct603 postfix/smtp[7455]: connect to dr.groupama-phoenix.com[195.170.5.242]:25: Connection refused
Oct 17 14:46:24 ct603 postfix/smtp[7455]: 433342606DE: to=<uwfd@groupama-phoenix.com>, relay=none, delay=252336, delays=252335/0.03/0.96/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to dr.groupama-phoenix.com[195.170.5.242]:25: Connection refused)
```

Comment: Without detailed, un-redacted logs from your mail server, showing us mail to that destination domain being sent out, it will be hard to efficiently give any advice on this issue.  Also, you shouldn't be running C6.5 on *any* production server; it is *way* out of support.

Comment: I have update my question according to your comments

Comment: Is that everything logged for that message? There should be more than that.

Comment: To get more data on attempted delivery to this domain you could add `debug_peer_list = groupama-phoenix.com` to `/etc/postfix/main.cf` (followed by `postfix reload`) as suggested at http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#debug_peer. After that you'll get more details for messages to that domain in the log file.

Comment: Another useful set of data would be the results of connecting manually to the preferred MX hosts for the domain. That might show you why postfix is falling through to the last MX. Get the list of MX hosts with `dig MX groupama-phoenix.com` and then try them in turn with (for example) `nc mail.groupama=phoenix.com. 25`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well how it actually works is that - MX records are DNS records telling mail servers where to deliver email for particular domain. Lets say you want to send an email to user@recepientdomain.com. The registrar of the domain recepientdomain.com will have one or more MX records which can look something like

mail.recepientdomain.com 10

mx2.recepientdomain.com 20

The name mail.recepientdomain.com points to some IP address destination at which lies the mail server of the recepient. It does not have to be the same as the IP address of recepientdomain.com. The 10 (or 20) after the MX name means the priority of each MX record - lower number = higher priority

Depending on your mail server configuration the server will most likely do one of two things when you send an email to user@recepientdomain.com:

1) It will deliver the email directly to recepients mail server - your mail server will ask the holder of the domain name recepientdomain.com what are the MX records for that domain. Then it will attempt to contact the mail server at mx records with lowest priority number and delivery the email. If it is not successful on that mx records it will try the next one (if there is one)

2) It will deliver the email to a superhost which will do the delivery to the recepient - it is basically same as number 1) just the superhost communicates with the destination mail server.

So my answer is that the problem is very unlikely to be your end as you dont control which MX record you are sending your email to (unless you really specifically want to).

You can use these commands to find out what their MX records are

```
nslookup
set type=mx
recepientdomain.com
```

For google.com it returns

> Non-authoritative answer:
>
> google.com    mail exchanger = 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
>
> google.com    mail exchanger = 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
>
> ......

And you can then look for the MX records in your postfix log file. Just tested it on mine and the MX information is recorded there as

> relay =

I hope this helps with your question

Comment: Thanks fro the info it was a really help. As you suggested nslookup shows me the mx records for the mails domain.  The mx where my mails trying to send is the fifth priority but is the firt in listing

Comment: Sorry previous comment is not complete.  According to nslookup the preference of the mx record my mail server is trying to connection is 50, although exists other mx records with preference 10, 20, 30, 40. Is there a way to find out why my mail server ignores lowest priority mx and for what reason?

Comment: Can you check if the other records work? You can test it for example by telneting.
"telnet mail.recepientdomain.com 25"

You should get either a response or at least black screen - that means you got connected and the mail server most likely works.
So test the other mx records like this. 

You can also check if the MX records on your end match those on Google DNS servers. Just enter server 8.8.8.8 before the set type=mx in the nslookup. nslookup; server 8.8.8.8; set type=mx; recepientdomain.com

Comment: I can see the other mx records responses on my logs files so I guess the are working. Unfortunatelly the responses are all "lost connection with xxxxxxx while receiving the initial server greeting".  By my research this message appears when smtp_connect_timeout is small, but my value is 3600s so this must not be the problem. Another think is that I might be blacklisted, but i am not, although I was 2 weeks ago, but after 2 weeks being clean, this should not be the problem. Is it possible to have a problem in HELO and how can I figure this out?